# Why does the modelbinder instantiate empty objects for my list in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have a json object like this:

```
var itemData = {
   "translations":[
      {
         "value":"Byron",
         "languageId":1             
      },
      {
         "value":"hgfdfghds",
         "languageId":3
      }
   ],
   "itemId":204,
   "itemCategoryId":44
};
```

And I POST it using jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "items/update",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: itemData,
});
```

When the call arrives at my ASP.NET MVC4 controller action, the non-list properties are assigned. However, the `translations` array only has two empty objects (instantiated, but with null/default property values). Here is my controller action method and my models:

```
public JsonResult Update(UpdateItemModel model)
{
    if(model.Translations[0].Value!="Byron")
    {
        throw new Exception("That translation's value should have been populated with 'Byron'.");
    }
    return Json("ok");
}

public class UpdateItemModel
{
    public List<TranslationModel> Translations { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int ItemCategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class TranslationModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
}
```

If I look at `Request.Form` in the immediate window, I can see that the `translations` "array" is encoded for some reason (maybe that's correct, not sure). If I try `Request.Form["translations"]` I get `null`. Here's an example of the raw form data that I'm seeing:

`{translations%5b0%5d%5bvalue%5d=Byron&translations%5b0%5d%5blanguageId%5d=1&translations%5b1%5d%5bvalue%5d=hgfdfghds&translations%5b1%5d%5blanguageId%5d=3&itemId=204&itemCategoryId=44}`

Not sure if my problem has anything to do with the "encoding" of the json at the beginning of that string. I looked at it in Fiddler and saw the same thing, so I can't blame ASP.NET for tampering.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the content type (json) and stringify it using [JSON.stringify](http://nuget.org/packages/json2/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "items/update",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    type: "POST",
    data: itemData,
    data: JSON.stringify(itemData),
});
```

Another thing to do is use add a **JsonValueProviderFactory**:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

in `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax`

This [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/30/whatrsquos-the-difference-between-a-value-provider-and-model-binder.aspx) might help you.

Comment: The problem was fixed without adding the jsonValueProviderFactory. The contentType and stringify-ing the data was the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you pass data for Ajax call is good to specify the content and stringfy the data:

```
$.ajax({
   /*More stuff*/
   data: JSON.stringify(itemData),
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: "json",
   type: "POST"
});
```

Then the value provider and the default ModelBinder will do the job.

Comment: #1 is incorrect. Property names are not case sensitive when modelbinding in ASP.NET MVC. #2 is correct, I needed the contentType and to stringify my data.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't knew this change!

Answer (score 0):

I can see the json object properties are not matching .net properties, In json you have "value" in .net "Value" case is different. Try making the case to march the .net model

Comment: I hope that's not the reason because nothing else is case-sensitive, but I'll try it. :)

Comment: No, same problem. I changed all c# properties to camel-case and the array is still populated with empty objects.